# Angular2: How to use pdfmake library

Tags: angular, pdfmake

Trying to use client-side pdf library [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) in my Angular 2 (version=4.2.x) project.

In .angular-cli.json file, I declared js like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js",
    "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"
  ]
```

And then in app.component.ts, I used it like this:

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   pdf: any;
   downloadPdf() {
    let item = {firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Parker'};
    this.pdf = pdfMake;
    this.pdf.createPdf(buildPdf(item)).open();
  }
}

function buildPdf(value) {
   var pdfContent = value;
   var docDefinition = {
     content: [{
    text: 'My name is: ' + pdfContent.firstName  + ' ' + pdfContent.lastName + '.'
     }]
   }
   console.log(pdfContent);
   return docDefinition;
}
```

I hit below error in browser console when loading the app:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (linebreaker.js:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (linebreaker.js:161)
at Object.../../../../linebreak/src/linebreaker.js (linebreaker.js:161)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b937441…:54)
at Object.../../../../pdfmake/src/textTools.js (textTools.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b937441…:54)
at Object.../../../../pdfmake/src/docMeasure.js (docMeasure.js:4)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b937441…:54)
at Object.../../../../pdfmake/src/layoutBuilder.js (layoutBuilder.js:7)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b937441…:54)
```

My workaround for solving this problem is:

Copy pdfmake.js and vfs_fonts.js to assets folder, and then add this to index.html:

```
<script src='assets/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
<script src='assets/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
```

Remove this from app.component.ts

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake';
```

And add this to app.component.ts:

```
declare var pdfMake: any;
```

Finally remove this from .angular-cli.js:

```
"../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js",
"../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"
```

It works but it's still a workaround.

Anyone knows how to use this library in Angular/Typscript way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Following the instruction above made by @benny_boe , I've made it work! Let me summarize it as below:

First,

```
npm install pdfmake --save
```

Second, add below to typings.d.ts:

```
declare module 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
declare module 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
```

Third, in the file where pdfMake is being used, either component or service, add below lines:

```
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Last, use pdfMake.xxx() as usual.

Comment: When you do it like this, you might end up with duplicates of the pdfmake. Try the `source map explorer` to inspect your bundles if you've got it in your `vendor` AND your `scripts` bundles..

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't have to add those 2 js to scripts section in .angular-cli.json. I've updated my post by removing the old second step. Thanks!

Comment: Is it [import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';] or [import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';] ?

Comment: If we follow this procedure, this is causing an issue while building with AOT. Does this happen with you guys too ?

Comment: @kharish Have you tried there `min` version...??? try to add `pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js` or `pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min`

Answer (score 13):

So first things first. You do **not** need to add you 3rd party scripts to the `.angular-cli.json` **AND** add an import in your TS files. Take a look at the [Global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) Story from the Angular CLI.

> Once you import a library via the scripts array, you should **not** import it via a import statement in your TypeScript code...

(There are no typings for `pdfmake` so you'll need to declare them when unsing the config file..)

So if you want to add it to your TS File... replace your `import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake';`  (its the server-side version!) with the client-side version (`'pdfmake/build/pdfmake'`). You'll also need to add the fonts (`'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts'`) otherwise you'll get an error too.

When your imports are looking like this it should work:

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work, and the error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pdfMake' of undefined. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I've made it work by following Global scripts story you mentioned. Thanks a lot! I'll summarize it in another reply.

Comment: Glad to hear that you've got it working! I've tried my solution with the latest beta of Angular CLI (1.3.0-beta.1) and it works. On what version are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Another simple approach when using global scripts according to angular-cli [Stories Global Scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts) if you follow the instruction carefully. **IF** the library doesn't have any typings.

**On angular-cli.json file**

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js",
  "../node_modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"
],
```

**ON src/typings.d.ts file**

Add `declare var pdfMake: any;` line below.

Now anywhere in your application the `pdfMake` global variable is now available.

Try to log pdfMake in the contructor or any init methods

```
ngOnInit() { console.log(pdfMake); }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    createdPdf: f(t),
    vfs: {
        Roboto-Italic.ttf: "some long encoded string...",
        Roboto-Medium.ttf: "some long encoded string...",
        Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf: "some long encoded string...",
        Roboto-Regular.ttf: "some long encoded string...",
    }
}
```

Which means it is ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i pdfmake;

import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
  var dd = {
    content: [
      {
        layout: 'lightHorizontalLines', // optional
        table: {
          // headers are automatically repeated if the table spans over multiple pages
          // you can declare how many rows should be treated as headers
          headerRows: 1,
          widths: [ '*', 'auto', 100, '*' ],

          body: [
            [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'The last one' ],
            [ 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4' ],
            [ { text: 'Bold value', bold: true }, 'Val 2', 'Val 3', 'Val 4' ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };
pdfMake.createPdf(dd).download();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.