# PdfMake Ionic 4 angular custom font to support Amharic language

Tags: angular, fonts, ionic4, pdfmake

```
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
pdfMake.fonts = {
    myFont: {
        normal: '../../../../assets/fonts/hiwua.ttf',
        bold: '../../../../assets/fonts/hiwua.ttf',
        italics: '../../../../assets/fonts/hiwua.ttf',
        bolditalics: '../../../../assets/fonts/hiwua.ttf',
    }
}
const docDefinition = {
    content: [ ....... ],
    defaultStyle: {
    font: 'myFont'
}
```

how can I add my custom font and support the Amharic language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you follow the steps in the [pdfmake guide for custom client-side font support](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/):

1. Place your font files (.ttf) in `/node_modules/pdfmake/examples/fonts/`
2. From the `/node_modules/pdfmake/` directory, run `npm install` then `gulp buildFonts`
3. Import the generated `/build/vfs_fonts.js/` file. My imports look like this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56535907/6119323)):

```
import * as pdfMakeConfig from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js';
pdfMakeConfig.vfs  = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
```

**Important**: In defining `pdfMake.fonts`, just use the filename, not the full path. Mine looks like this:

```
pdfMakeConfig.fonts = {
    ethiopic : {
        normal: 'NotoSansEthiopic-Regular.ttf'
    }
};
```

Then you can use it in document descriptions like this:

```
{
    text: 'foo',
    font: 'ethiopic'
}
```