# using custom font pdfmake for angular

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I am following this [documentation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side) of custom fonts of `pdfmake`. I am not able to understand that how can I follow this example of Angular 4+ because my `pdfmake` file is in node module and it will be change if i transfer my project or clone into another system.

I add `pdfmake` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136111/angular2-how-to-use-pdfmake-library)