# font loading issue with pdfmake in ionic/ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, pdfmake

I'm using pdfMake for generating PDF in ionic/angular. It's working fine with android but getting error in iOS when loading font dynamically.

I'm loading font in this way

```
generatePDF(pdfInstant: any, content: any) {
  pdfInstant.fonts = {
    common: {
       normal: `${window.location.origin}/assets/fonts/pdf/FreeSerif.ttf`,
       bold: `${window.location.origin}/assets/fonts/pdf/FreeSerif.ttf`,
       italics: `${window.location.origin}/assets/fonts/pdf/FreeSerif.ttf`,
       bolditalics: `${window.location.origin}/assets/fonts/pdf/FreeSerif.ttf`,
     },
   };

   content['defaultStyle'] = {
     font: 'common'
   };
   pdfInstant.createPdf(content).getBase64((r: any) => {
      this.utilService.sharePDF(new Date().getTime() / 1000 + '.pdf', r);
   });
}
```

Error I'm getting is:

`⚡️  [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): File 'capacitor://localhost/assets/fonts/pdf/FreeSerif.ttf' not found in virtual file system`

Comment: You probably have only to remove window.location.origin from the path

Comment: @Nibia Not working like that. Getting same error